# angular-chart.js legendCallback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, angular-chart

I can't seem to make the `legendCallback` work.

I tried putting it like this:

```
options = {
    legend: {
        legendCallback: function (chart) {
            console.log(chart);
            return 'a';
        }
    }
}

OR

options = {
    legend: {

    },

    legendCallback: function (chart) {
        console.log(chart);
        return 'a';
    }
}
```

I also tried switching `legend` and `legendCallback` in the second one but still doesn't work nor give any error.

Comment: can you provide plunker ...

Comment: I could, if it is necessary. But base on the snippets that I gave. Which is the correct part to add the `legendCallback`?

Answer (score 1):

The legendCallback function is setup on the options, run by Chart JS and then made available to your calling code via a call to chartInstance.generateLegend() which will generate the HTML for you to append to an element on the page.

```
var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        legendCallback: function (chart) {
            console.log(chart);
            return 'a';
        }
    }
});

// This runs the legendCallback and returns the result
var legendHtml = chartInstance.generateLegend();
```

Comment: Can you add a comment to explain why it wasn't working and what have you done to fix it?

Comment: The legendCallback function is setup on the options, run by Chart JS and then made available to your calling code via a call to chartInstance.generateLegend() which will generate the HTML for you to append to an element on the page. Updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Chart.js docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#polar-area-chart-chart-options), `legendCallback` is a global option i.e.

```
var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        legendCallback: function (chart) {
            console.log(chart);
            return 'a';
        }
    }
});
```